# What model/significance test should I use to see if there's any significance between male and female sexual dimorphism on temperature over time?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, model, fitting

In my lab I need to test if there's an significance between male and female sexual dimorphism on body temperature over 40 minutes. The temperature is simulated with a heat lamp and is turned on at 0 minutes and stays the same for the duration of the experiment. I've done multiple trials, and for each trial there's 9 data points collected (temperature collected from male and female every 5 minutes). Is there a model I can fit in R, and a significance test (T-test?) that would fit best for my data? Should I do a permutation test?

Thank you!
[image]

(Green: Female, Blue: Male)

Answer (score 0):

You should log-transform the temperature to try to linearize it and then do an ANCOVA of the form `log(Temperature) ~ Time + Sex`.

You might have to try log-transorming time as well, if the log-transformation of temperature alone is not enough to achieve linearity on the temperature-time graph for each sex.

See more info and examples [here](http://www.biostathandbook.com/ancova.html).

Comment: That might work well, thank you so much! I will look more into it.